# How to trigger an event after splash screen disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, objective-c, jquery-mobile

I am very new to mobile app development.I have some issue that how to call a javascript function when my first page of the document shows immediately after the splash screen disappears
I am using the below code but it is not working.Please suggest on this

```
- (void)viewDidAppear : (BOOL).animated
{
    NSString * JSCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myFunction();"];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:JSCallback];
}

function myFunction(){
    // some code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

call the javascript function in viewDidLoad() rather than viewDidAppear()